# Reload div after select combination

Tags: jquery, select, reload

I have got two dropdownlists (select, option). If I change one of these, it should show a differant image immediately.

```
            <select id="1" class="selectpicker show-tick">
                <option value="70">70</option>
                <option value="80">80</option>
                <option value="90">90</option>
            </select>
            <select id="2" class="selectpicker show-tick">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>

            <embed id="mapembed" src="http://xyz.com/80_1.svg"type="image/svg+xml"/>
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript"> // that the select works
  window.onload=function(){
  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
  };
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#1, #2').change(function(event) {
    $('#mapshow').html("http://xyz.com/" + $('#1').val() + "_" + $('#2').val() + ".svg"); // to see if it works as text
    $('#mapembed').src("http:/xyz.com/" + $('#1').val() + "_" + $('#2').val() + ".svg"); // does not reload!
}); 
</script>
```

If I use the .html it shows the correct path as text output after every click(change). However whith the .src it does not change the image.

I am using jquery, bootstrap, and bootstrap-select

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap code inside `document.ready`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#1, #2, #3').change(function(event) {
        $('#mapshow').html("http://xyz.com/" + $('#1').val() + "_" + $('#2').val()
           + ".svg");
        $('#mapembed').attr('src',"http:/xyz.com/" + $('#1').val() + "_" + $('#2').val()
           + ".svg");
    }); 
});
</script>
```

and also replace `.src('` with `.attr('src',`

Comment: @hrhax have you changed `.src` to `.attr`.?

Comment: i must confess I did not. 
Now it is still not working on chrome, but it does on FF. If I look at my source in the dev console (chrome) I see the code has changed, but the image stays the same. Strange..